# What does the <i subscript mean?

Tags: conditional-probability

$$z_i \sim p_i(z_{i}|\theta, z_{<i})$$  I saw this in a paper and have googled a lot to try make sense of the exact meaning. It seems to be non-standard notation looking at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols). Seems to say that the subscript in $$z_{<i}$$  is strictly less that `i`. Is this the correct interpretation?

The paper reference is [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.01429.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this paper notation $z_{<i}$ is used to denote a vector of $(z_0,z_1,\ldots z_{i-1})$. The term $p(z_i|\theta,z_{<i})$ should be understood as “the probability of state $z_i$ given parameter $\theta$ and all previous states $z_0,\ldots z_{i-1}$”

Comment: Thanks @vasily, is this vector notation from linear algebra or something?